# Android SQlite - Working with Dynamic tables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am building an Android native mobile application and I need to create tables dynamically with user input in my Application. By reading the documents, it looks like I cannot use **SQLiteOpenHelper** since Table needs to be created only in constructor or in `onCteate()` method. So I created my own utility class with **`SQLiteDatabase`** initialised. With this instance, I created a database and a table. When I query for the tables in the DB, I got an error stating **`java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase`**

How to open and close SQlite database properly without extending **SQLiteOpenHelper** class . I need to query the data from different activities depends on the need for data. Is there any tutorial available which matches my need ?

To create Database

```
public static SQLiteDatabase phiDatebase;

public void createOrOpenDatabase(String dbNmae, Context context){
        this.dbName = dbNmae;
        try{
            uuiDatebase = context.openOrCreateDatabase(dbNmae, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Log.i("UUI_LOG","DB CREATED");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

To create table,

```
public void createSurveyTable(String tableName, String queryString){
    try{

        uuiDatebase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + "(" + queryString + ");");
        Log.i("UUI_LOG", "TABLE CREATED");

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But when i query for table list, I am getting the error.

```
Cursor res =  uuiDatebase.rawQuery( "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null );
res.moveToFirst();
```

Below is my complete class to Craete DB, Create Tables and get list of tables.

```
public class UUIDBHelper {

    public static SQLiteDatabase uuiDatebase;
    public static String dbName = "";


    public void createOrOpenDatabase(String dbNmae, Context context){
        this.dbName = dbNmae;
        try{
            uuiDatebase = context.openOrCreateDatabase(dbNmae, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Log.i("PHI_LOG","DB CREATED");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void createSurveyTable(String tableName, String queryString , boolean isCreate){
        try{
            if(isCreate) {
                uuiDatebase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + "(" + queryString + ");");
                Log.i("PHI_LOG", "TABLE CREATED");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public Cursor getAllTables() {

        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  uuiDatebase.rawQuery( "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        return res;
    }

    public Cursor getSurveyNames(String tableName) {

        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  uuiDatebase.rawQuery( "SELECT survey_name FROM "+tableName+" WHERE id=0", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        return res;
    }


}
```

Here is the Logcat result

```
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837): **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked** (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:634)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:320)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:294)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1142)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1131)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:261)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at surveytool.uui.com.uuisurveytool.UUIDBHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(UUIDBHelper.java:24)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at surveytool.uui.com.uuisurveytool.ListCreatedSurvey.onResume(ListCreatedSurvey.java:54)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1241)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6023)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2940)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2982)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-28 13:28:12.922: E/SQLiteDatabase(2837):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: There's something wrong in your code. Which you have kept secret. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can u share logcat errors?

Comment: Do provide full class extending sqliteHelper. That might give us more idea to understand where the cause is.

Comment: I am not extending sqliteHelper class. I need to create 'n' number of Tables dynamically WRT user input. Can it be done even by extending sqliteHelper class ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you close the database anywhere ?

Comment: I tried closing the database after a transaction. But even after that I got the same issue. So I removed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if SQLITE operations were performed without using SQLiteOpenHelper classs, DB needs to be opened and closed manually.

```
public static SQLiteDatabase dbInstance ;

dbInstance = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

And close when the transaction is completed.

```
dbInstance .close();
```